# Solr - get range facets inferior to a threshold

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 4.3. I have built range facet for field price, for which I gave a `f.price.facet.range.start`, a `f.price.facet.range.end` and `f.price.facet.range.gap`, but I cant figure out how to compute the facet for values inferior or superior to a certain value.

Maybe I dont know the exact syntax :  `f.price.facet.range.other.before=1000000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on on [Facet Range Other](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.range.other), this will only work for values that fall within the range being computed. So for your example, if 1000000 is not within your current range start/end values, you will not get a result from the `range.other.before` parameter. However, you can still get the facet for this price, by including it as a separate [facet.query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_%3a_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting) request.

For your example, you would include te following parameter:

`facet.query=price:[* TO 1000000]`

Comment: I understand that my syntax is correct, I have to just add a `facet.query` sentence.